# Allow lower reps to see removed answers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Many times I have had answers and found out they were invalid due to a obscure meta post. But people have said things like: "This is the 3rd time people have done this and it is still not funny", "This is *still* invalid just like the other removed answers". I can't see those answers and I believe ~500+ should be able to see removed answers to help avoid this. BUT they can't see who made this answer.

Comment: This was prompted by me, I assume?

Comment: +1 because I'd like to see this problem discussed, even if I don't necessarily think the suggested solution is the best one.

Comment: Personally I think 1000 would be a more reasonable threshold

Comment: Do people usually view the deleted answers, especially on highly answered questions, before posting?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Well, I won't post an answer if I see than an identical solution has been deleted...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yeah and me too but that doesn't mean everyone looks into the deleted answers before posting.

Comment: Just an FYI, I'm pretty sure that if (when) we fully graduate, rep thresholds for deleted answers/questions, by default, go up. SO has mod tools at 10,000 rep.

Comment: @Okx partially but those comments are from other unnamed users

Comment: @TheLethalCoder yeah I just gave my best idea

Comment: @StephenS Yeah that is true please don't do that SE

Comment: Is this really such a big problem? If anything, deleted answers just create clutter and are an eyesore

Comment: @BetaDecay well if answers you think are valid are not and others have tried that it reduces the eyesore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## There's nothing we can do about this

The perk of seeing deleted answers are set on 2000 rep, and is set by the SE team. It's not a local rule to set reputations for these perks.